# Git checkout branch not working

Tags: linux, git, branch

I am new in git and trying to understand what is wrong here.

```
[root@root /]# git describe --tags
16.0.13-7-g56099d7
```

Try to upgrade to 16.0.15 branch or tags (got error)

```
[root@root /]# git checkout 16.0.15
error: pathspec '16.0.15' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Trying different way (no error)

```
[root@root /]# git checkout -b 16.0.15
Switched to a new branch '16.0.15'
```

But still showing older version

```
[root@root /]# git describe --tags
16.0.13-7-g56099d7
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: Why do you believe that `16.0.15` is a valid tag name? The `git describe` output proves that `16.0.13` is a valid tag name, but nothing else in your output indicates that any other tags at all even exist. (There probably are other tags, but you should show *why* **you** think there are other tags.)

Comment: This is what i am trying to do https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible/pike/user/minor-upgrade.html  Step: 2  (git checkout 16.0.15)

Comment: Oh wait i did `git tag` and i didn't find any 16.0.15 (i think you are right)

Comment: I found its pointing to `https://git.openstack.org/openstack/openstack-ansible` new URL is `https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible`  how do i switch this URL  in git?

Comment: If you see `16.0.15` tag is visible here in https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible

Comment: OK. When did you clone the repository, and have you run `git fetch` (or `git fetch --tags`) since then?

Comment: _"trying different way"_ worked because you _created_ the branch.

Answer (score 0):

First, change to an appropriate directory, you seem to be doing this at root or `/` level. If possible you should also change user to something other than `root`.

---

Next, clone the repo from the new location;

```
git clone https://github.com/openstack/openstack-ansible.git
```

then change into the cloned repo's directory;

```
cd openstack-ansible/
```

checkout the desired branch;

```
git checkout 16.0.15
```

lastly, follow the rest of the instructions at https://docs.openstack.org/openstack-ansible/pike/user/minor-upgrade.html